# Can you help me with this simple RobotC exercise?

Tags: nxt, robotc

I mean 2. Second Length found [here](http://robotc.net/tutor/NXT/nxt.php?platform=NXT&unit=robotcfundamentals&lesson=3)

I think I found all mistakes but still, I can't seem to get the right answer.

1. On line 8 it should be wait1Msec(3000); instead of wait1Msec(4000);
2. Swing turn to the right should be written as 100 power for C and 0 power for B. I also tried -100 for B and even exchanged letters just in case I misunderstood which of the motors is left and which is right, but I still got the wrong answer (according to the website).

There are mistakes in the comments as well, but that shouldn't be a problem since they're just comments! Still, I corrected them just in case. Replaced 4 with 3 and replaced right with left, still not correct.

Do they expect me to right some specific text in the comments? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Try and keep your question self-contained by putting any code related to it in the body of your question. External links are not only annoying, they're sometimes impossible for people to load due to various firewall restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you should write the code for your second length after the comment

```
//END OF FIRST LENGTH
```

So, your code should be a code for the first length and the second length. I hope that helps.

Comment: That was it! I would've never figured that out probably, thanks a lot! Sorry, can't mark your answer as the correct one because my 'reputation points' aren't enough.